# Sort Map<String, dynamic> in flutter dart where the first key is the field name

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have a document with fields that are generated in firebase, the field name is todays date and the value is a incremenation of a use when the user do a special thing in the app.

When i retrieve the data from firebase my Map<String, dynamic> statistics; is filled in a random order because of how data is retreived from firebase.

How can i sort the returned data on the Key value (string) so that the dates are in ascending order?

I just can not figure this out. Any hint pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are okay with lookups being O(log n) instead of O(1), you can use a [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) which keeps entries in a sorted order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `key:value` bro, it doesn't exist such thing as **order** so it **can't sort**. It's a Map, just call key and it return value.

In case you really want to do this. Get `keys` of the map and sort, use sorted keys to create new map in order.

```dart
void main() {
  var map = {"b": {}, "d": {}, "a": {}, "h": {}, "f": {}, "c": {}};

  var newmap = {};
  var keys = [...map.keys]..sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  for (String key in keys) {
    newmap[key] = map[key];
  }

  print("oldmap: $map"); 
  print("newmap: $newmap");
  // result
  // oldmap: {b: {}, d: {}, a: {}, h: {}, f: {}, c: {}}
  // newmap: {a: {}, b: {}, c: {}, d: {}, f: {}, h: {}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, your solution actually proves that the keys do have an order. Otherwise the solution wouldn't even work. It's true that maps in general don't have a key order, but the standard map in Dart does have it. But yeah, other kinds of maps in other languages might not have that.

Comment: @IvoBeckers I mean a map is used key/value then why we need order in a map

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedKeys = map.keys.toList()..sort();
```

try this or use the below plugin

```
sortedmap: ^0.5.1
```

import 'package:sortedmap/sortedmap.dart';

```
main() {
  var map = new SortedMap(Ordering.byValue());
  
  map.addAll({
    "a": 3,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 4,
    "d": 1
  });
  
  print(map.lastKeyBefore("c")); // a
  print(map.firstKeyAfter("d")); // b
  
}

import 'package:sortedmap/sortedmap.dart';

main() {
  var map = new FilteredMap(new Filter(
    compare: (Pair a, Pair b)=>Comparable.compare(a.value, b.value),
    isValid: (Pair v) => v.key!="b",
    limit: 2));
  
  map.addAll({
    "a": 3,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 4,
    "d": 1
  });
  
  print(map.keys); // (d, a)
  
}
```